# Remove leading digits from a string with Bash using parameter expansion

Tags: bash, parameters, parameter-expansion

The initial string is `RU="903B/100ms"`
from which I wish to obtain `B/100ms`.

Currently, I have written:

```
#!/bin/bash
RU="903B/100ms"
RU=${RU#*[^0-9]}
echo $RU
```

which returns `/100ms` since the parameter expansion removes up to and including the first non-numeric character. I would like to keep the first non-numeric character in this case. How would I do this by amending the above text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [BASH_REMATCH](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) to extract the desired matching value:

```
$ RU="903B/100ms"
$ [[ $RU =~ ^([[:digit:]]+)(.*) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
B/100ms
```

Or just catch the desired part as:

```
$ [[ $RU =~ ^[[:digit:]]+(.*) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
B/100ms
```

Comment: Thank you! Would up vote but according to stackoverflow my gratitude is temporarily meaningless since I'm new here ;)

Comment: @AASJC your kind words are way more meaningful than some virtual points :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `shopt -s extglob`:

```
RU="${RU##+([0-9])}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "903B/100ms" | sed 's/^[0-9]*//g'
B/100ms
```

Comment: Thanks, but preferably by using parameter expansion? This is a special case of a more general task I'm doing